# Difference in height of root Layout calculated from two methods

Tags: android, listview

I am calculating the height of a root Layout ( RelativeLayout) with height and width as `'fill_parent'` using this method and it returns 690

```
 final RelativeLayout rootLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        ViewTreeObserver vto = rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {

                rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                mRootLayoutHeight=rootLayout.getHeight();
                 Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this,""+mRootLayoutHeight,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            }
        });
```

This layout has a `Listview` so i calculate the calculate the 'bottom' of individual rows using this

```
for(int i = 0; i <= month_listview.getLastVisiblePosition() - month_listview.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++){

            View v=month_listview.getChildAt(i);
            if(v!=null) {

                Rect rectf = new Rect();
                v.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);
                Log.d("bottom       :", String.valueOf(rectf.bottom));

            }

        }
```

The bottom of the last row should come as 690 but its coming as 776. Why is there a difference?

Comment: What makes you think that the last row matches the relative layout? If you scroll the view you will get different values. The view's end is outside of bounds because it's a listview.

Comment: But its giving bottom values for only the visible portion of that row.

Comment: Is rectf.top == 0? I mean is the first element located at the top (0).

Comment: No @user3249477 actually its 140? Why is that so?

Comment: No. You're saying it's `776`. that's more than `690`. That means that the end of the view is 86 pixels bellow the RelativeLayout

Comment: Perhaps padding/margins are at play here. Also try using getMeasuredHeight(). Anyways your second piece of code is a bad way to measure a container.

Comment: @user3249477 getMeasuredHeight() returns 690 for root. The listview first row's top starts at 115 and last rows bottom is 800. But it should have been 0 and 690\